# How to define new and existing customers on Power Bi using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I would like to define 2 sets of customers to identify number of product opens per year and the type of customer they are:

Existing Customer Adds Product - these are customers who had an existing account with us previously (previous year) but then decided to open up a new product with us

New Customer - this is customers who have only opened an account this year with us but also opened a new product too

I have an account level table example:

```
Account Code    Account Open Date
12345           04/02/18
12389           09/09/20
43244           23/10/19
```

I also have a product level table example:

```
Account Code    Product Code    Product Type    Product Open Date
12345           12345RED        Red             09/02/18
12389           12389RED        Red             09/11/20
43244           43244BLACK      Black           03/03/20
```

Based on the year and also the account date opened and the product open date i would like to define if the customer is a new or existing customer in a new column.

Example: If Customer A opened an account in 03/03/2019 and this customer opened a new product in 20/10/2020 this customer will be an existing customer who has a product.

if Customer B opened an account in 03/06/20 and this customer opened a new product within 60 days (05/07/20) this customer is a new customer

if customer c opened an account in 03/05/20 and this customer opens a new product after 60 days (09/12/20) this customer is an existing customer adds product

please could you help me on this.

thank

Comment: The question is not very clear, please stick to the template: (0) Context, (1) Problem, (2) Example, (3) Expected Solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a general Business Intelligence applied to Power BI, to slice-and-dice your facts based on whether the Customer was Existing or New **on the Event date**, **you need to defined an attribute on the Fact table itself**.

Going one step further, the practical implementation consists of:

1. define a new dimension: `Customer Type` with an attribute `Type`: {Existing, New}.
2. **in the back-end**, add the Foreign Key of this new dimension `Customer Type` to your Fact
3. in the Front-end use Customer Type dimension to slice-and-dice over your facts based on whether the customer is Existing or New